# How to declare a private integer?

Tags: java

I am getting an

> "Illegal start of expression"

error in the following code at the location marked by a comment. How can I correct this error?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    private int w=5; //Problem here"Illegal start of expression"//
    private int Pw=0xb7e15163, Qw=0x9e3779b9;
    private int[] S;
```

Comment: How would you do it in normal class ? Anyway **`access modifiers`** are not for **`local variables`** but for **`instance variables`**. I hope you understand the difference.

Answer (score 4):

- Firstly, a point on question title: *declaring private integer in netbeans.* Netbeans is an IDE and you are actually trying to *declare private integer in Java source code*, this is happening irrespective of IDE's used.
- Secondly, what is `private` keyword in Java? It is a access level modifier.
  And [access level modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) determine whether other classes can use a particular field or invoke a particular method. So, it is getting applied to members of a class - instance fields, instance methods.
- In your case,

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      // TODO code application logic here
      private int w=5;
  ```
- Variable `w` is getting declared and defined within the method `main`. And `main` method is within your class. So, variable `w` *does not qualify to become a member of the class*. It is a local variable which has scope within `main` method. So, access level modifier cannot be applied to variable `w` which has been defined within method `main()`. That is the reason why you get *"Illegal start of expression"*. Within a method, it is not syntactically/semantically correct to specify access to a variable.

Comment: Since you already noticed that "netbeans" is unrelated here, you could also edit the question to remove that :). Btw this bulletpoint list looks kind of strange, because the last too look like they belong together :P.

Comment: I was trying to guide the OP to get some clarity. Anyways, thanks for the edit. :)

Comment: You're welcome. You need 8 whitespaces (instead of 4) to "start" a code block if you're in a list (numbered or bulleted) :).

Comment: Oh Thanks. I shall start using this from the next answer/edit onwards. :)

Comment: thanks a3.14_infinity, you solution really helpfull X'D

Answer (score 2):

`private` variables have access modifiers because they are *instance* fields. They go outside the method. You'll need an instance to use them, and you'd normally need accessor and mutator methods (because they're `private`, only this `class` can access them; that does include `main`) -

```
private int w=5; 
private int Pw=0xb7e15163, Qw=0x9e3779b9;
private int[] S;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThisClass tc = new ThisClass();
    System.out.println(tc.w);
}
```

Comment: thanks elliot, you solution really helpfull X'D
already four days I was confused because it can not solve this problem X'(